# Polynomials are dense in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know that the function $e^{inx}$ can be uniformly approximated on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by polynomials in $x$. I want to use this to show that polynomials are dense in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$.

Suppose that $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. I want to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a polynomial $p$ such that $|\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f(x)-p(x))^2dx|<\epsilon$. I was thinking about writing $f$ in terms of its coefficients, i.e. $$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}$$ But I'm still not sure how this can lead to the polynomial $p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists some $N$ so that

$$\left\|f(x)- \sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n)e^{inx} \right\|_2 < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Now for each $-N \le n \le N$ you can find some polynomial $P_n$ so that

$$\left\| \hat{f}(n) e^{inx} - \hat{f}(n)P_n \right\|_2 < \frac{\epsilon}{2(2N+1)}$$

Now prove that
$$P= \sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n) P_n$$
works.

Comment: And here you're using that the partial sums of the Fourier series converge to the function itself in $L^2$, right? I remember this to be false in $L^1$, but for $L^2$ it should work well.

Comment: (there is no need to approximate each term in the truncated Fourier series by a polynomial: the truncated sum is continuous so you can approximate the whole thing at once. (and it is not easier to approximate an exponential  than a finite sum of exponentials :-) ))

Comment: @MikaH. Yes, the FS converges in $L^2$.

Comment: I wonder how Mika H. Knows he can find those polynomials, as he said that he does not know the S-W theorem!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think this one is easy, isn't it? Just by the expansion $e^{inx}=1+inx+(inx)^2/2!+\ldots$. Then the partial sum converges to $e^{inx}$ since the tail is clearly small.

Comment: Ah. That works nicely :-) (notice that the same argument gives you an approximation  to the partial Fourier series, not only to each of its terms separately)

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35134/elegant-proof-that-l2a-b-is-separable/35142), the linear combinations of characteristic functions of intervals are dense in $L^2$, so it is enough to show that you can approximate these arbitrarily well in the norm of $L^2$ by polynomials.

Can you do that?

Comment: It seems too advanced for me. Would it be possible to prove using the fact I stated at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

The polynomials are dense in $C[\pi,\pi]$, and we can think of $C[\pi,\pi]$ as a subset of $L^2[\pi,\pi]$.

Furthermore, $L^2[\pi,\pi]$ is the completion of $C[\pi,\pi]$ with respect to the $L^2[\pi,\pi]$ norm. Hence the polynomials are dense in $L^2[\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: It seems too advanced for me. Would it be possible to prove using the fact I stated at the beginning?

Comment: It is, @N.S. has provided such a proof. Note that the first part of the proof mirrors the fact that $L^2$ is the completion of $C[-\pi,\pi]$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm, and the second part utilizes the fact the the polynomials are dense in $C[-\pi,\pi]$.