# If $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g^n(x)dx=0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; $ then $\; f \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let g be continuous, not negative, and strictly increasing in [a, b]. Prove that if $f$ is continuous and
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g^n(x)dx=0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$$
then $f\equiv 0$.

With a change of variable I have arrived here but I could not continue: 
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)u^n \frac{du}{u'}=0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$$

Two particular cases already resolved by the community are:

$g(x)=x$ and $x \in [0,1]$: $\quad \int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^ndx=0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; $
then $f\equiv 0$.

$g(x)=e^x$: $\quad \int_{a}^{b}f(x)e^{nx} dx=0, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; $
then $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: This is basically saying that $\{g^n(x)\}$ is dense in $L^2$ for any continuous, non-negative, strictly increasing $g$ in $L^2[a,b]$. That equates to the following : given a function $f \in L^2$,  there exists a sequence  in the span of $\{ g_n(x)\}$ that converges to $f$ in $L^2$. Try to prove the weaker fact that there exists such a sequence that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. (which is implied by, but does not imply $L^2$ convergence). A counterexample here, will be a counterexample for the larger case as well.

Comment: Your change of varaible leads to the well-known $x^n$ case, but needs differentiability.

Comment: Could you give an answer and explain in more detail?

Comment: How would it be?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  $\{g^n\}$ has not to be dense in $L^2$. For example take $g(x) =x$ then the sequence $\{x^n\}$ convergences to $h(x)=0$ in $L^2$ so it can't be dense in $L^{2}$

Comment: @nonlinearthought I meant *the span of* $\{ g^n\}$ should be dense in $L^2$, not $\{g^n\}$ itself. The span of $\{ x^n\}$ is indeed dense in $L^2[a,b]$,since given a function in $L^2[a,b]$, we can find a polynomial (which is in the span of $x^n$) that is arbitrarily close to it in the $L^2$ sense.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  can you please prove that, or put here a reference about this density, since this is way stronger than the question here.

Comment: @nonlinearthought I thought this question was easier than the one  given here , anyway : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548713/polynomials-are-dense-in-l2

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version).

Comment: Is $\mathbb N = \{1,2,\dots \}$?

Comment: @zhw I'm sorry for not clarifying, in this case $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots \}$, that is, $n = 0,1,2, ...$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the problem statement, $g$ is a homeomorphism $[a,b]\to [c,d]$. The continuous function $f\circ g^{-1}\colon [c,d]\to\Bbb R$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials. So for $\epsilon>0$, we find $p\in\Bbb R[X]$ with $|f(g^{-1}(t))-p(t)| <\epsilon$ for all $t\in[c,d]$, or equivalently $|f(x)-p(g(x))|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int_a^bf(x)^2\,\mathrm dx&=\int_a^b f(x)p(g(x))\,\mathrm dx+\int_a^bf(x)(f(x)-p(g(x))\,\mathrm dx \\
&\le\rlap{\qquad0}\hphantom{\int_a^b f(x)p(g(x))\,\mathrm dx+}\llap{+\;\epsilon}\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}$$
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary $>0$, we conclude $\int_a^bf(x)^2\,\mathrm dx\le 0$ and therefore $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: If $\mathbb N = \{1,2,\dots \}$ there's a little more to do.

Comment: @zhw I'm sorry for not clarifying, in this case $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots \}$, that is, $n = 0,1,2, ...$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen For $g$ to be a homeomorphism, only $g$ need to be bijective and both $g$ and $g^{−1}$ need to be continuous. Where do you use that $g$ is non-negative?

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity let assume $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and first suppose $g(x)=x$ taking into account the particular case, we have $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) p(x) = 0 $ for each $P(x) = polynomial$.

now since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then there exists a sequence of polynomials, say $P_n$ such that $P_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly. This implies that
$$  0= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) p_n (x)  \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 $$ Hence, $\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 =0$, and because $f$ is continuous we arrive $f=0.$
Now let W.L.O.G assume $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is onto (otherwise you can scale this g) this implies $0=g(0),~ 1=g(1)$ now by substitution $y=g(x)$ the condition of question becomes $$  \int_{0}^{1} F(y) y^n dy =0 $$ where $F(y) = f(g^{-1} (y)) (g^{-1} (y))'   $ hence according to my pervious argument $F=0$ which implies $f=0$

Some Clarifications :

Note that since $g$ is strictly increasing so $g^{-1}$ is. And it is a well-known fact that every increasing function has almost countable non-differentiable points, thus $g^{-1}$  is differentiable a.e.  Therefor it does not impact on the integrability and the value of integral. Thus this makes $F=0$ a.e and then $f=0$ a.e and since $f$ is continuous $f=0$ every where!.

P.S for those who have hard time of scaling $g$, if $[g(0) , g(1)] \neq [0,1]$ you can scale this $g$ in this way $\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{g(1)-g(0)}.$

Comment: People who voted down this answer, Please tell why?  put comment here.

If you cant understand my solution that doesn't meant it is wrong !!!!

Comment: where your function $g^n$ here ?

Comment: The question presumes some arbitrary, fixed function $g(x)$. It doesn't say that the equality holds for *any* function $g(x)\,$, so you don't get to choose the $g(x)\,$.

Comment: Look at  bottom of question.  and what I write here  "taking into account the particular case" !

Comment: @divx  look at my solution again , I added few lines to it, is it clear for you?

Comment: even if you can assume that $g(x)$ is onto (which I don't think your scaling argument is correct), $g^{-1}$ does not have to be a well-defined function. You need injectivity to assume the inverse function.

Comment: @divx  all I am saying is that first  we solve problem for special case when $g(x)=x$. Then for general case where $g$ is an arbitrary function , by substitution of $y=g(x)$ we can turn problem into particular case again !

Comment: @dezdichado  do you know what strictly increasing means ?!!

Comment: I make it more clear like 3 times!! I don't care if people are still voting down my solution, since they can't understand it ! I myself love my solution!

Comment: @nonlinearthought I removed my downvote since your later clarifications, though I am not entirely convinced that this approach must work. I still don't see why $g^{-1}$ would *have* to be differentiable, which was one of the first comments posted under OP's question.

Comment: @dxiv  thanks,  since $g$ is strictly increasing so $g^{-1}$ is. And it is well-known fact that every increasing function has almost countable non differentiable points, so it is almost every where differentiable so it does not impact on integral. so this make $f=0$ almost every where and since $f$ is continuous $f=0$ every where!

Comment: Differentiability a.e. is not enough for the purposes of changing variables in the integral. In general, using an increasing substitution $x \mapsto y$ fails if you only use the derivative a.e. (unless the substitution is absolutely continuous). You need to consider the distributional derivative (which is a finite positive measure) and prove that $F=0$ as a measure.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Here $g$ is indeed an absolutely continuous function, since it is continuous and increasing.  Plus I suggest you to look at 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: @miguel   Note that at bottom of your question you yourself considered the interval [0,1], that actually holds true for any interval [a,b]. (just follow the first part of my argument with [a,b] instead [0,1]), then  for general case $g:[a,b] \rightarrow [g(a),g(b)]$ is onto and all things likewise follow from the first argument if you consider interval $[g(a),g(b)]$ instead $[0,1]$ for second integral

Comment: No, $g$ does not have to be absolutely continuous (and the comment section is not the right place to convince you). Yes, I guess using the Riemann-Stielstjes could lead to the proof, as it is equivalent with the Lebesgue integral (if $g$ has bounded variation).

Answer (score 1):

Hagen von Eitzen above has indeed given an elegant solution valid when the given g is strictly increasing but no assumption that g be non-negative is needed or used. However it is not necessary assume the integral (1) I[a,b]f(x)(g(x))^n dx =0 for all non negative integers n= 0.1,2,3...   . It suffices to assume this for integers 
n >= M where M is any positive integer and by increasing M we  assume M is odd .We use the Stone Weierstrass theorem instead of the Weierstrass Theorem .Note that (1) implies that I[a,b]f(x) (g(x)^M (p(g(x))dx =0  for all polynomials If g(x) is never 0 in [a,b] then g(x)^M is strictly increasing hence the algebra of functions of the form (2)q(x)= (g(x)*M (p(g(x)) separates the points of [a,b] and don't all vanish at any one point and so  dense in the continuous functions for the mac norm .Using such a sequence converging to f(x) uniformly we see that I(f(x)^2 ) =0 so f vanishes identically as before
 What happens if g(c) = 0 for some c in [a,b] (exactly one ,g is strictly increasing . Then  the functions of the form C + q (q as in (2),C a real constant ) are a dense set . But if h(c)=0 H continuous then a sequence of functions c+q oonverges uniformly to h and all q(c)=0  hence the sequence of constants c tends to 0 so the the sequence of q 's =c+q -c tends to h uniformly . Take h = f T  where T(x) is between 0 and 1 ,T(c) =0 .and T=1 off and interval of length e containing c , T continuous  then see that I (f^2T) =0 Let e tend to 0 to get I(f*2)=0 and hence f=0 .  Stuart M.N.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). And you don't need to add your signature, it's visible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, re-attempt. Assume $f$ is not identically zero. Then there exists at least one point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$ and say w.l.o.g. that $f(x_0) > 0$ (otherwise just take the negation). Since $f$ is continuous, there is a small neighborhood around $x_0$ where $f>0$ in that interval. Since $g$ is non-negative and increasing, this implies that

$$
\int f(x)\,g^n(x)\,dx > 0
$$

Which is a contradiction to the original statement. Thus $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: `it must follow that` No, it only follows that $f(c)=0$ for some $c\,$.

Comment: oops, you are right. I'm a dummy

Comment: I reattempted this problem if you want to take another look.

Comment: The integral could be positive on that `small neighborhood`, but be negative on others, and add up to $0$ on the whole interval $[a,b]\,$ in the end, so there is no contradiction there.

Comment: @Cocomos Your proof would have worked, if $f$ were assumed to be at least non-negative.

Comment: @Paichu This is true, but then the problem becomes trivial - even assuming $\int f g^n = 0$ for one value of $n$ would suffice.