# Complete orthonormal sequence on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm working on a problem dealing with complete sequences on Hilbert spaces. An orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is called **complete** if the only member of $H$ orthogonal to each $e_n$ is the zero vector.

I know that an orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$ is complete if and only if $\|x\|^2=\sum_1^\infty|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2$ for all $x\in H$. Further, for any $x\in H$ we can write
$$
x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
Below is the problem I am tackling:

> Prove that $(e^{2\pi inx})^\infty_{n=-\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal sequence in $L^2(0,1)$.

I have shown that $(e^{2\pi inx})$ is orthonormal; that is, $\langle e^{2\pi inx},e^{2\pi imx}\rangle=\delta_{nm}$.

Now I am trying to show that it is complete by showing that if $x\in H$ and $\langle x,e^{2\pi inx}\rangle=0$ for every $n$, then $x=0$. Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: This is   a basic theorem in the theory of Fourier series, In particular Fourier Series by Edwards has  a proof.

Comment: Do you know Liouville's Theorem from Complex Analysis? If so, a direct proof is possible without knowing any convergence theorems for the Fourier Series.

Answer (score 0):

To prove completeness you need to work with density of $C[0,1]$ in $L^2[0,1]$ [as stated here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2588183/836910).